# How to create an INI file with custom key value separator and data lines enclosed by double quotes?

Tags: inno-setup

I would like to write into a file with the given structure the following string (it's like an INI file but as the key value separator is used space instead of `=` char, and data lines are enclosed by double quotes):

```
[view_my_note]
"notepad C:\Program Files\My Program\p\"
```

using the `[INI]` section in Inno Setup:

```
[INI]
Filename: "{app}\myprog.ini"; Section: "view_print_command";
  Key: "notepad"; String: "{app}\private\"; Flags: createkeyifdoesntexist
```

I'm able to get the output like this:

```
[view_print_command]
notepad=C:\Program Files\My Program\p\
```

But the key values are separated by the `=` chars and it's missing the enclosing double quote chars for data lines, which our legacy software cannot read. The structure of the file is like INI file except that:

- the key values must be separated by the space chars
- the key value lines must be enclosed by double quotes

How can I create such file in Inno Setup ?

Comment: I've quite radically modified your question. At least you forgot to mention that the data lines are enclosed by double quotes. Could you take a look on it and optionally rollback my revision, please ? Also, the script samples you've posted do not match to the code and your desired result. You wanted `[view_my_note]` section, but wrote the `[view_print_command]` one. Except that, value `{app}\private\ ` won't produce `C:\Program Files\My Program\p\ `, but at most `C:\Program Files\My Program\private\ `. But never mind, it is not an INI file anymore. What do you need to do with that file ?

Comment: Thanks for the response..<br>

Comment: That was merely a correction :-) The `[INI]` section cannot be used for the file with this structure (well, could be, but the produced file would have to be modified after, so better will be to handle this file from `[Code]` section). So, what we need to know is what are you going to do with that file. Are you going to generate a brand new file ? Or even modify an existing one ?

Comment: I would want to generate a brand new file and also require it to be modified when a reinstall is done. Chances are there that the user could change that ini with a different path. A reinstall should override with defaults.